# Find the Coordinates of A,B and C

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

A plane π has vector equation $r =(-2 i+3 j -2 k )+λ(2 i
+3 j+2 k )+μ(6 i-3 j +2 k)$.
(a) Show that the Cartesian equation of the plane $\Pi$ is $3x+2y-6z=12$.
(b) The plane $\Pi$ meets the x,y and z axes at $A, B$ and $C$ respectively. Find the coordinates of $A, B$ and $C$.

I used the Normal vector to solve the (a) part, but i don't know to find the coordinates of $A, B$ and $C$. If the plane meets the axis is it not intercession?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

1. The $x$-axis, for instance, has equations $\; y=z=0$. So you only have to solve for $x$. Similarly for the other axes.
2. Rewrite the equation in the form:
   $$\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac z c=1.$$
   The intersections with the axes have coordinates
   $$(a,0,0),\quad (0,b,0),\quad (0,0,c).$$

Comment: Oh thanks. I guess i didn't know the general form of breaking the Cartesian equation into Coordinates. Thanks man

Comment: A(4,0,0), B(0,6,0), C(0,0,-2)